# how to pass list item with strings as parameter to web api in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a web api in which i am passing two list item other string parameters, all string parameters getting passed but only list parameters getting null in web api. Here is my code.

```
    public class CourseDetails
    {                       
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }            

        public List<SuggestedAndFAQ> SuggestedReadingList { get; set; }
        public List<SuggestedAndFAQ> FAQList { get; set; }            
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string SaveCourse([FromBody] CourseDetails CD)
    {
        string strResult = "N";
        using(ICALMSAdminEntities db= new ICALMSAdminEntities())
        {
          // My code
        }
    }
```

Calling web api...

```
public string SaveCourse(CourseDetails CD)
    {
        string uri1 = "http://xxx/myWebApi";
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            string newUri = uri1 + "/SaveCourse";                
            string myParameters = "Name=" + CD.Name + "&Domain=" + CD.Domain + "&Price=" + CD.Price+ "&SuggestedReadingList=" + CD.SuggestedReadingList + "&FAQList=" + CD.FAQList;
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(wc.UploadString(newUri, myParameters));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not posting data in correct format(JSON). you can use PostAsJsonAsync method with WebClient like :

```
CourseDetails classDetails= CourseDetails
{
// set data in CourseDetails instance
};

string uri1 = "http://xxx/myWebApi";
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
var response = wc.PostAsJsonAsync(uri1, classDetails).Result;

// other stuff

return  response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CourseDetails>().Result;

}
```

Comment: please share error details. as in this example json data is being sent.